# I can't reference my class library

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution that contains two projects developed in visual studio 2012 express, and both targeting the .net framwork 4.5.

the first "Dao" project purpose is to take data from a database. and take these data to the second project as a dll library

the second project "UI" purpose is to display data coming from dll library

when i added reference to the second project and wrote using statement, I got the following error:

The type or namespace name 'Dao' could not be found (a using directive or an assembly reference missing?)

I tried to change the target of the two projects to .net framework 4.0 and .net framework 3.5 , but I got the same error.

I also add this piece of code to be sure that the target is change but I got true :

```
using System;

using Dao; // error

namespace Ui
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Type.GetType("System.Reflection.ReflectionContext", false) != null);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to fix the problem? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Does the `Dao` namespace exist in the Dao project?

Comment: Have you *actually* added a reference to the assembly (in solution explorer) as well as just adding the `using` directive to import the namespace? They're different things. Are the types within the `Dao` namespace public?

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing something before that root NS like Business.DataLayers.Dao?

Comment: public class CLASSNAME

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem is I didn't put 'public' before my classes on dao project like "WhileTrueSleep" and "Jon SKeet" they said . thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first:

1. Add a reference to Dao - in source explorer right click references->Add->projects tab.
2. Add a using statement at the top of your code something like using Dao;
3. Ensure Dao is a public class

This way your code will know to reference Dao, it is usually better to create a new instance of Dao:

```
Dao example = new Dao();
```

Then when calling Dao you would call example instead, so example.(name of method)

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a reference to your Dao assembly from your UI assembly.  Right Click on References, Add Reference.  In the Projects tab, select your Dao project and hit OK.